# How to read truncated data in telnetlib

Tags: python, telnet, wireshark, telnetlib

Using wireshark I captured telnet packets. While analyzing captured packets I get the data part as,

```
Data [truncated]: 17:46:26......****....
```

My question is, Now I initiate telnet connection via telnetlib in python. Through that I send and receive data. But sometimes while receiving the data, it is truncated as shown above. So, Is it possible to read those truncated datas programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `tshark` with the *telnet* dissector disabled?  For example, when live capturing you could use something like so:

```
tshark -i foo --disable-protocol telnet -f "tcp port 23" -Y "tcp.len > 0" -T fields -e frame.number -e data
```

That will capture all telnet traffic but will display the frame number and data fields from only those packets that actually contain data.  It requires that you disable the *telnet* dissector for it to work.  Note here that I'm using the `--disable-protocol` command-line option to disable *telnet*, but if you're running an older version of `tshark`, which doesn't have this option, then you will have to disable the *telnet* dissector in Wireshark first via *"Analyze -> Enabled Protocols... -> Protocol:Telnet"* before running `tshark`.

Here is a similar example, but this time `tshark` is reading packets from a file rather than live-capturing them:

```
tshark -r foo.pcap --disable-protocol telnet -Y "tcp.port eq 23 and tcp.len > 0" -T fields -e frame.number -e data
```

And if you prefer, you can also change the output format of the data to include colon-separators (`':'`) between the bytes like so:

```
tshark -r foo.pcap --disable-protocol telnet -Y "tcp.port eq 23 and tcp.len > 0" -T fields -e frame.number -e data.data
```

You can specify as many fields as you want using `tshark`'s `-e` option.  Refer to the [`tshark man page`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information about `tshark` and its various options.